# jquery returns undefined reading json

Tags: jquery, json

Using the following code, I am trying to read sample data from the link `https://data.mo.gov/resource/hsus-bft8.json`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head> 
<body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("https://data.mo.gov/resource/hsus-bft8.json", function(data){
            document.write(data.licensee + "<br>");
            document.write(data.street_number);
        }).fail(function(){
            document.write("An error has occurred.");
        });
    });
    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

but it simply returns 2 `undefined` fields. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here your missing the loop, because it is a array.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head> 
<body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("https://data.mo.gov/resource/hsus-bft8.json", function(data){
            var len = data.length;
            for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                document.write(data[i].licensee + " : " );
                document.write(data[i].street_number + "<br/><br/>");
            }
            
        }).fail(function(){
            document.write("An error has occurred.");
        });
    });
    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

An array is being returned. You need to loop on the complete array/ use index to print those properties. Try following code

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("https://data.mo.gov/resource/hsus-bft8.json", function(data){
            
            data.forEach( elem => {
                document.write(elem.licensee + "<br>");
                document.write(elem.street_number);
            });
            
        }).fail(function(){
            document.write("An error has occurred.");
        });
    });
    </script>
```